# Cherrypy can't find options when using apache?

Tags: cherrypy

I've been having a strange problem with cherrypy. When I quickstart an application:

```
cherrypy.quickstart(WebApps(), '/dev/apps/', 'settings.config')
```

Everything works fine. However, when I try to load my application through apache mod_wsgi, it seems that none of the default options from the options file are passed to the tool I created.

I basically have a simple tool:

```
@cherrypy.expose
@cherrypy.tools.checkStatus()
def doSomething(self,*args, **kwargs):
   #process the page here
   ...

def checkStatus(**kwargs): 
    #handle stuff here
```

and a very simple settings.config file:

```
[global]
tools.checkStatus.redirect = 'http://localhost/dev/MyRedirectPage.html'
tools.checkStatus.returnAfterRedirect = True
```

As stated above, when I run from the quickstart function, checkstatus is passed a dictionary of parameters, containing 'redirect' and 'returnAfterRedirect'.

Whenever the app is launched from mod_wsgi, the code runs, but no paramters are passed to kwargs.

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    app = cherrypy.tree.mount(WebApps(),
                              '/dev/apps/', 
                              os.path.join(currentPath,'settings.config'))

return app(environ, start_response)
```

Am I missing something obvious here? Why does the first version work and not the second?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by verifying that `os.path.join(currentPath,'settings.config')` is what you think it should be...

But assuming it is, then try moving your config entries from `[global]` to `[/]`. `quickstart` will pass the same config to both `cherrypy.config.update` (the global config) and `app.config` (application-specific config), but `tree.mount` only does the latter.

Comment: I manually called cherrypy.config.update with the settings file, AS WELL AS passing the settings file as an argument in tree.mount. That seemed to do the trick. You have to do both if you want access to the globals and the app/specific settings. Thanks